# How to limit the number of page numbers in one line of an index?

Tags: pdftex, indexing, makeidx

[image: Index excerpt]
I'm using PDFLaTeX and makeidx to compile an index for a book. Some of the index entries have many page numbers associated. The first line includes so many page numbers that there is no space, or in this case, dots between the entry name and the first page number. See the image.

I'd like to limit the number of entries such that there is some minimum amount of space between the entry name and the first number - say, at least 3 dots. Or I'd like to have an even distribution of page numbers across the first line and next wrapped line. Or any good solution that provides more space.

I tried to decrease the size of the indentation in the IST file, but it didn't work.

My IST file looks like this:

```
%MakeIndex style style file IndexStyle.ist

% Reduce size of indent from default '16' to '8' - to try prevent page numbers squashing against entry name
indent_length 0
indent_space "\t"

% Big letter for Index headings
heading_prefix "{\\bfseries\\hfil "                  % Insert in front of letter
heading_suffix "\\hfil}\\nopagebreak\n"              % Append after letter
headings_flag    1                                   % Turn on headings (uppercase)

% Add dots between entry and page numbers
delim_0 "\\dotfill "
delim_1 "\\dotfill "
delim_2 "\\dotfill "
```

Comment: If you are willing to leave out some numbers in the index then of course you can also remove the index entries from the document body as a workaround (for example go to the text corresponding to page 124 and remove the command creating the index for Peter Harvey).

Comment: @Marijn Thanks, but it's not really an option since I'm working to the author's specification as to what needs to be indexed.
I also realise that I could add spaces or dots in each entry, but I'm looking for a general solution and knowledge as to how to best use the IST file, or some other solution which I can apply as a rule.

Comment: My suggestion was based on the phrase "I'd like to limit the number of entries" in your question - I guess I misunderstood and you meant "the number of entries per line" instead of "the number of entries per index item".

Answer (score 2):

LaTeX defines `\dotfill` as:

```
\def\dotfill{%
  \leavevmode
  \cleaders \hb@xt@ .44em{\hss.\hss}\hfill
  \kern\z@}
```

The problem here is that `\hfill` can have a minimal width of 0 which isn't what you want.

So, you can change your `.ist` file to use, e.g., `\mydotfill` instead of `\dotfill` and then define `\mydotfill` as:

```
\def\mydotfill{%
  \leavevmode
  \cleaders \hbox to .44em{\hss.\hss}\hskip 1em plus1fill
  \kern 0pt}
```

and this will ensure that you have at least 1em of leader dots.

Comment: Thanks Don, that is brilliant! I'd have never have thought to do it that way, works perfectly. I'm in awe of the levels of expertise and helpfulness on here.